# Linux / UNIX / OS X Binary Directory Structure

Tags: linux, mac-osx, unix, path

Will Linux / UNIX / OS X binaries be stored in the same directories across different platform or distributions? I'm asking because I need to have access to `uuidgen` (stored in /usr/bin/uuidgen on my development computer) and noticed that my local Apache server does not include `/usr/bin` in the `PATH`. I know I could add `/usr/bin` to the path, but I want to make sure the software can be re-deployed on a number of different systems with ease. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on it being there. You should use the `which` command to find it's path i.e. `which uuidgen` will find it in the user's path. If it's not there, you could use `locate uuidgen` to try and get it.

Comment: Will `which` always be located in `/usr/bin`?

Comment: `which` is a shell builtin.

Comment: You beat me to it. +1 to you!  (and Congrats on the new gig!)

Comment: What exactly does a shell built-in imply? The program running under Apache can't find `which` either.

Comment: @Sam which is actually NOT a builtin command - in bash anyway. Which has been at /usr/bin/which on every system i've used. Also the fact apache can't find it makes me think it is running as a user that doesn't have a shell. What user is apache running as?

Comment: Heh. Forgot, using `zsh`. In any case, when you're using `which`, specify the full pathname. Since `/usr/bin` isn't in your path already, you'll need to assume (and use) `/usr/bin/which`.